# SBT sync throws an error "Cannot add dependency" on intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I get the following error on IntelliJ why I run `sbt sync`

```
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/tushar/Documents/Projects/zio-rocksdb/"), "zio-rocksdb") / updateSbtClassifiers' for the full output
[error] (ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/tushar/Documents/Projects/zio-rocksdb/"), "zio-rocksdb") / updateSbtClassifiers) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add dependency 'com.typesafe#ssl-config-core_2.12;0.4.0' to configuration 'default' of module dev.zio#zio-rocksdb$sbt_2.12;0.2.0+3-114b41b9+20200418-1131 because this configuration doesn't exist!
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed 18-Apr-2020, 11:31:05 AM
```

**build.sbt**

```scala
name := "scala-interview-scheduler"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

// ZIO Core
lazy val zioVersion = "1.0.0-RC18"

// Project Scheduler
lazy val scheduler =
  (project in file("scheduler"))

// Project Storage
lazy val storage = (project in file("storage"))
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "io.suzaku" %% "boopickle"   % "1.3.1"
    )
  )
  .dependsOn(ProjectRef(file("../zio-rocksdb"), "zio-rocksdb"))

// Project Program
lazy val program = (project in file("program"))
  .dependsOn(scheduler)

// Testing
ThisBuild / libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "dev.zio" %% "zio"          % zioVersion,
  "dev.zio" %% "zio-test"     % zioVersion % "test",
  "dev.zio" %% "zio-test-sbt" % zioVersion % "test"
)

ThisBuild / testFrameworks += new TestFramework("zio.test.sbt.ZTestFramework")

// Global Options
ThisBuild / scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-language:postfixOps",
  "-language:implicitConversions",
  "-feature"
)
```

What does it mean?